# Salto hacia atras en menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menú

tengo una web en wordpress que dispone de un menu donde, cuando pulsas, este hace autoscroll hacia una id specifica.
He creado una seccion que se llama News y que muestra los ultimos post de una categoria con un link que, si pinchas, abre un single.php con la noticia en grande.
El problema viene cuando, usando el en el single.php el mismo menu, al tener solo la id y estas no estar presentes el el archido donde se habre la noticia no hace nada.
He tratado de usar en el menu la url de la web + la id (www.url.es/#id), pero solo firefox resuelve esto, chrome no, se que no es correcto, pero no encuentro otra manera.
aqui dejo como se refleja el menu

```
<div id="main_nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'main-nav',
            'menu_id'        => 'menu-main_menu',
            'container'      => '')); ?>
</div>
```

Sabeis como añadirle un salto hacia atras a este menu?
Gracias de antemano